# How to control audio sound through UIswtch of on and off

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, uiswitch

Playing sound for click sound when date is selected in the date picker. Now i need to set my setting module for control ON and OFF using UISWitch.
How to set my control of sound to uiswitch .

```
-(void) switchforSounds:(id)sender 
{ 
    if ([sender isOn]) 
 {
     [Appdelegate.infoObj playback];

  }
 else 
 {

 }
}

        -(void) playback
        {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click" ofType:@"caf"];
        if (path)
        {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];

        SystemSoundID soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)url, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and easy:

```
if(myUISwitch.on){
    [self playback];
}
```

If that wasn't what you were looking for, I can always revise it.

Comment: aquila . I am calling many method and class my [self playback]; so i need to stop my playback ., it is possible to stop using  soundID .

Comment: I think that if you want control over stopping sounds you need to use something a little bit more heavy than the module you're using (can't remember what it's called, but I know it's meant for ringtone style stuff). Try core audio and the media player components (I have no experience with them).

Comment: Have any idea how to normal stop in playback in OFf mode of UIswitch

Answer (score 0):

if the question is how to bind the switch in IB to your function

`-(void) switchforSounds:(id)sender` the answer is

1. declare it like this:

   `- (IBAction) switchforSounds:(id) sender` in your .h and .m file respectively.
2. right click on the switch in IB, you will see all events it can respond to. Choose changeValue event. Click in the hook near it and drag to the File's Owner element in your IB'c controller file. When you leave the mouse it's supposed to show you all IBAction selectors you've defined in your controller class. Choose switchforSounds.
3. Done.
4. Hopefully i understood your question right.

Comment: through coding i am build my switch , i need how to check audio is play or off , right now i am just calling method to some  some function , now i am going to control switch.I understand by IB , how to do programmatically